# has_one :through through a join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

I want to build something so that a person can have many email addresses and an email address has only one person, but because I also have another model called Company that also can have many email addresses, and I don't want to have columns company_id and person_id in the Emails table, so I thought I can do ...

## person.rb

has_many :person_emails
has_many :emails, :through => :person_emails

## person_emails.rb

belongs_to :person
belongs_to :email

## email.rb

has_one :person_email
has_one :person, :through => :person_email

What's happening now is that...

p = Person.first #=> "Nik"
p.emails #=> shows all emails Nik has
p.person_emails #=> shows all person_email joint table records for Nik

e = Email.first #=> one of Nik's email addresses
e.person_email #=> shows this email's one and only one person_email joint table record
e.person # fails saying that unknown column "people.email_id" in where-clause

I'd like...
e.person #=> "Nik"

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your situation suggests using polymorphic associations, which are much cleaner than `has_many :through` associations. For example:

```
class Person
  has_many :emails, :as => :emailable
end

class Company
  has_many :emails, :as => :emailable
end

class Email
  belongs_to :emailable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

You can get rid of your `PersonEmails` class entirely. In the database, your `emails` table will look something like this:

```
create_table :emails do |t|
  t.string :address
  t.string :emailable_type
  t.integer :emailable_id
end
```

The `emailable_type` column stores the name of the associated model, in your case `"Person"` or `"Company"`, and the `emailable_id` stores the id of the associated object. For more information see [the Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) under "Polymorphic Associations".